# How to space items with positition absolute

Tags: html, css

I am developing a navbar in the top left of the page.
To prevent it from moving the content far down, I set the position to absolute.
My problem now, is that each item is overlapping.

```css
.nav-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
}
.nav-item:hover p {
    color: #909590;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <a href="index.html">
            <section class="nav-item">
                <img src="assets/home.svg" alt="home">
                <p>Home</p>
            </section>
        </a>
        <a href="commissions.html">
            <section class="nav-item">
                <img src="assets/dollar-sign.svg" alt="dollar-sign">
                <p>Commissions</p>
            </section>
        </a>
    </nav>
```

Comment: First obvious thing, you are misspelling **section ** in the second one. But that isn't your actual problem.

Comment: Why do you put a `position: absolute` on every element instead of the container itself?

Comment: Yeah I know. I just quickly wrote up a second item but before that I had it deleted because it was breaking.

Comment: tacoshy you are a life saver! for some reason it won't let me mark this as solved though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the `position`-property to the container instead of every single element (which causes the collision):

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
}

/* original CSS */
.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-item:hover p {
  color: #909590;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="index.html">
    <section class="nav-item">
      <img src="assets/home.svg" alt="home">
      <p>Home</p>
    </section>
  </a>
  <a href="commissions.html">
    <section class="nav-item">
      <img src="assets/dollar-sign.svg" alt="dollar-sign">
      <p>Commissions</p>
    </section>
  </a>
</nav>
```